# Looping through ranges to print specific slides in powerpoint with VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I've tried to print with this, or a macro similar and it worked, I exported, then excel crashed.  I then was not able to get this to work after relaunching.

The macro should loop a number of times input by the user, then prints the first slide (title) and 5 additional slides indexes in multiples of the number of times looped onto a 6 slide handout.

- First page: 1, 3-7
- Second page: 1, 8-12
- Third page: 1, 13-17
- etc.

This now throws an error:

> Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)
>
> Method 'PrintOut' of object '_Presentation' failed

Below is my script.  Ideas?

```
Sub CHPrint()

    Dim oIndexArray(0 To 5) As Integer, slideIndexArray(0 To 5) As Integer, numCases As Integer

    ' Prompt user for how many cases to print (# pages, # loops)
    numCases = InputBox("How many cases to print?")

    ' Initialize first index of array to 1 (first slide).  This will not change.
    slideIndexArray(0) = 1

    ' Initialize other indices of array to the first set of slides to print (3-7)
    For i = 1 To 5
        oIndexArray(i) = 3 + (i - 1)
        slideIndexArray(i) = oIndexArray(i)
        Next i

    ' For each loop, select slides to print (1&3-7; 1&8-12; 1&13-17; etc.) and print
    For i = 0 To numCases - 1

        ActivePresentation.Slides.Range(slideIndexArray).Select

        With ActivePresentation
            With .PrintOptions
                .ActivePrinter = "LN104142 on LocalHost"
                '.ActivePrinter = "Adobe PDF"
                .OutputType = ppPrintOutputSixSlideHandouts
                .RangeType = ppPrintSelection
                End With
            .PrintOut  ' "method 'printout' of object '_presentation' failed"

            End With

            ' For each time through the first loop (i), reinitialize selection (1&3-7; 1&8-12; 1&13-17; etc.)
            For j = 1 To 5
                slideIndexArray(j) = oIndexArray(j) + (5 * (i + 1))
            Next j

        Next i

End Sub
```